# I need regular expression that will receive exactly 9 digits starting with 5

Tags: regex

I have tried many alternatives but I am not reaching anywhere

```
/^[5]\d{9}$
```

can someone help.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex must be like below,

```
^5\d{8}$
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
/5[0-9]{8}/
```

First a five, and then 8 times a digit.

Comment: I appreciate your effort.But the expression is not meeting my requirements../^\(?([5]{1})\)?([0-9]{8})$/

Comment: What requirements, if I may ask? (And what's with a heavy modified version of my regex?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to match anywhere, use this

```
/5\d{8}/
```

If you want it to be on a line by itself, use this instead

```
/^5\d{8}$/
```

The caret (^) means it must occur at the start of a line, and the dollar ($) means it must occur at the end of a line.

Comment: I appreciate your effort.But the expression is not meeting my requirements.

Comment: I found an expression which is working properly. That I am sharing it with you./^\(?([5]{1})\)?([0-9]{8})$/